Is there a way to securely run an "interactive" program without a keyboard?
My laptop is connected to the internet by wifi only, but it occasionally gets disconnected. When that happens, I cannot ssh into it, and must physically login to reconnect the wifi with nmcli (I didn't setup any graphics).
Unfortunately, some of the keyboard keys are unresponsive, which are required for the user login and wifi password.
Thus I've setup a user account whose name uses only keys that work and whose login "shell" is a script to reconnect the wifi:
#!/usr/bin/bash

if /usr/bin/nmcli device wifi connect 'SSID' password 'PASSWORD'; then
    echo "Connected as $(ip -json -4 address show wlp2s0 | jq -r '.[0].addr_info[0].local')"
else
    echo 'Failed to connect to wifi'
fi

read -sN 1 -p 'Press any key to exit...'

wirec:x:970:969::/:/opt/wirec/wirec

This is definitely not a great setup, but it works while I wait for a new keyboard to arrive. I also figured out NetworkManager has an auto-reconnect feature, which is really all I want. It did make me think, though:
In a general case, where a program is expecting sensitive interactive input, and with no network connectivity, and there is no keyboard, is it possible to get the input to the program? Or is writing it down when there is network to run when there isn't as good as it gets?

Have you looked into writing an expect script?


In a general case, where a program is expecting sensitive interactive input, and with no network connectivity, and there is no keyboard, is it possible to get the input to the program?

Well, it comes down to what kinds of input devices the program is willing to accept.
Note that command-line programs like nmcli are using a TTY device for input, not specifically a keyboard. So anything that can be represented as a TTY device will work: if your laptop has a RS-232 serial port, or an USB-to-serial adapter, you could easily use that for command-line sessions, but you would need some hardware that would act as a terminal at the other end of the serial cable.
With most Linux distributions, some minimal set-up is also required. For example, in modern distributions using systemd, you would typically need just a single command to make the system persistently accept logins on /dev/ttyS0 serial port: systemctl enable --now serial-getty@ttyS0.service.
If you are willing to write a custom TTY device driver, then basically anything goes: if all you can have for input is a single data wire and a ground wire, you could make a TTY device that accepts input by Morse code, for example. Unless you are already proficient in Morse code, you might still prefer something that can visually display characters for the output side, though :-)
If the available hardware is already covered by existing drivers and you don't want to do kernel-level programming, there are ways to do it in userspace too. The simplest way would be to use your desktop environment's facilities to assign custom key actions to things like mouse button events; then you could use a multi-button gaming mouse as a replacement of a number keypad, for example.
Or you could take the source code of utilities like screen or tmux and re-write their input handling to read whatever input device (or even a raw set of GPIO pins) is available to you; the utility would then handle setting up a pseudo-TTY (PTY) device that could be used to run any interactive TTY-based program using your custom input hardware.

Isn't this kind of thing precisely what expect is for?

Sure, if the OP is willing to place the "sensitive input" in some plaintext-equivalent form (= plaintext or reversibly obfuscated) into the script. And then anyone who can read the script can gain access to the sensitive input, which would not be secure.

I use script (https://linux.die.net/man/1/script)
echo typed via pseudotty |
  script -q -f -c the-command-to-run

But for your special case I would use rina and leave that running in a tmux or screen:
ping 8.8.8.8 | rina /usr/bin/nmcli device wifi connect 'SSID' password 'PASSWORD'

If you cannot ping 8.8.8.8 for 10 secs, run the command.
Replace 8.8.8.8 with your ISP's router.
rina: https://git.data.coop/tange/tangetools/src/branch/master/rina
